# IDEA: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My Jetbains IDEA encountered a major error. When I run any project, including a new project, the standard output window show below:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\kent\IdeaProjs\Demo\src\main\java\com\kent\Test.java

BUILD FAILED C:\Users\kent\IdeaProjs\Demo\src\main\java\com\kent\Test.java:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Total time: 0 seconds

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And the content of Test.java only is :

```
package com.kent.test;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("hihi");
   }
}
```

Comment: That error is an XML error, it suggests that you are trying to run the .java file as an ant build.xml. Please explain in detail what you are doing and how you set up your project, because whatever it is, it is the wrong thing

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: `Buildfile: C:\Users\kent\IdeaProjs\Demo\src\main\java\com\kent\Test.java` Test.java is definitely not a **build** file. It is a java source code file. Build files are written in xml, or groovy/kotlin, ...

Comment: Probably you should include the steps for how you created the project. It is unusual that IntelliJ would pick up a Java file as the build file. This certainly did not happen for me when I followed the Intelli-J new Project / Java wizard (using your test program).

Answer (score 3):

maybe i am too late but i had the same problem. The problem was that i had a plugin for ant that recognized the tests as ant files. It worked after removing it

Comment: The plugin that had been interfered in test execution was Ant Debugger